# How to un-flatten and image after performing regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, reshape

Here is how I flattened these  images:

```
N = images.shape[0]
images = np.reshape(images, (N, -1)) 
images_two = np.reshape(images_two, (N, -1))
```

How do I reverse this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the original shape before flattening:

```
old_shape = images.shape
N = images.shape[0]
images = np.reshape(images, (N, -1)) 
images_two = np.reshape(images_two, (N, -1))

## to reshape

images.reshape(old_shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
num_imgs = images.shape[0]
img_shape = images.shape[1:]

images_flat = images.reshape((num_imgs, -1))

images_unflat = images_flat.reshape((num_imgs, ) + img_shape))
```